# Kendo UI Grid from Html table - change event will not fire

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid, where the dataSource is an html table.
I am trying to fire the `change:` event, but it will not fire.

Here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/tp2g68m1/)

It's based on [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/from-table)

And the change event [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events)

I bind to the `#grid` as follows :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: products,
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          ProductName: { type: "string" },
          UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
          UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
          Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
        }
      }
    },
    pageSize: 20
  },
  height: 550,
  scrollable: true,
  sortable: true,
  filterable: true,
  pageable: {
    input: true,
    numeric: false
  },
  columns: [
    "ProductName",
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px"  },
    { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
    { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
  ]
});

var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
grid.bind("change", function (e) {
    alert('CHANGE EVENT...') 
});


Perhaps it's not possible where the DataSource is an Html table. I'm not certain of this.

Thank you in advance...
Bob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ain't the `change` event...  the problem is that the grid didn't receive any `selectable` value.  Without this configuration value, the user won't be able to select any cell (or row), even if the `change` event was registered correctly.

Here's your updated code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: products,
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          ProductName: { type: "string" },
          UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
          UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
          Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
        }
      }
    },
    pageSize: 20
  },
  height: 550,
  scrollable: true,
  sortable: true,
  filterable: true,
  selectable: "multiple cell",  //<--- Just add this line
  pageable: {
    input: true,
    numeric: false
  },
  columns: [
    "ProductName",
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px"  },
    { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
    { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
  ]
});



var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
grid.bind("change", function (e) {
    alert('CHANGE EVENT...') 
});
```

You can also try it in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tp2g68m1/5/) jsfiddle example.

Here's a [link](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-selectable) to the selectable documentation.